# How can i route my Home component from the code below without throwing uncaught TypeError in the console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-icons

I'm having troubles displaying the Home component. How can I get this to work?

console display Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'string')
at ./node_modules/react-icon/lib/index.js

I'm using

```
    my versions are: 
     "react": "^18.1.0",
"react-dom": "^18.1.0",
"react-icon": "^1.0.0",
"react-icons": "^4.4.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",
```

And my codes are:

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom' 


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

My codes are:

Navbar.js

```
import React from 'react'
import './NavbarStyles.css'
import Logo from '../assets/logo.png'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import {FaBars,} from 'react-icon'

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <header>
        <nav className='navbar'>
            <div className='logo'>
                <Link to='/'><img src={Logo} alt='' /></Link>
            </div>
            <ul className='nav-menu'>
                <li className='nav-item'>
                    <Link to='/' className='nav-link'>Home</Link>
                </li>
                <li className='nav-item'>
                    <Link to='/' className='nav-link'>Services</Link>
                </li>
                <li className='nav-item'>
                    <Link to='/' className='nav-link'>Events</Link>
                </li>
                <li className='nav-item'>
                    <Link to='/' className='nav-link'>Contact</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div className='hamburger'>
                <FaBars />
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Navbar;
```

My codes are:

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/Home';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
    </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My codes are:

Home.js

```
import React from 'react'
import './HomeStyles.css'
import Navbar from './Navbar'

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        <Navbar />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

I think the issue is in the `NavBar` component. It is trying to import a named export from `react-icon`. `react-icon` doesn't export any specific icon components, instead it exports a single default export (*i.e. `import Icon from 'react-icon';`*) that uses props to specify which icon should be rendered. `react-icon` looks like an older/outdated package that fails to work with newer versions (React 15.5+) of React.

[`react-icon/src/index.js`](https://github.com/nkt/react-icon/blob/master/src/index.js)

> ```
> const React = require('react');
>
> const Icon = React.createClass({
>   displayName: 'Icon',
>   propTypes: {
>     glyph: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired, // <-- issue likely here
>     classPrefix: React.PropTypes.string,
>     children: React.PropTypes.node
>   },
>   statics: {
>     defaultFontPrefix: 'fa',
>     setDefaultFontPrefix(prefix) {
>       Icon.defaultFontPrefix = prefix;
>     }
>   },
>   render() {
>     const prefix = this.props.classPrefix || Icon.defaultFontPrefix;
>     let className = `${prefix} ${prefix}-${this.props.glyph}`;
>     if (this.props.className) {
>       className += ` ${this.props.className}`;
>     }
>
>     return (
>       <span {...this.props} className={className}>
>         {this.props.children}
>       </span>
>     );
>   }
> });
>
> module.exports = Icon;
> ```

React removed the [`PropTypes` into its own package since React 15.5](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html), so in the code above `React.PropTypes` is undefined and throws an error when trying to access the `string` property object.

## Solution

Import the `FaBars` icon from `react-icons` instead of `react-icon`.

```
import React from 'react';
import './NavbarStyles.css';
import Logo from '../assets/logo.png';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { FaBars } from 'react-icons'; // <-- import from `react-icons`

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <header>
      <nav className='navbar'>
        <div className='logo'>
          <Link to='/'><img src={Logo} alt='' /></Link>
        </div>
        <ul className='nav-menu'>
          <li className='nav-item'>
            <Link to='/' className='nav-link'>Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li className='nav-item'>
            <Link to='/' className='nav-link'>Services</Link>
          </li>
          <li className='nav-item'>
            <Link to='/' className='nav-link'>Events</Link>
          </li>
          <li className='nav-item'>
            <Link to='/' className='nav-link'>Contact</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div className='hamburger'>
          <FaBars />
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
};
```

You'll probably want to also remove `react-icon` from your project since it's so outdated. As of today (13/06/2022) the repo hasn't had an update in 7 years! Uninstall it by running the following command from the project's root directory.

```
npm uninstall --save react-icon
```

Comment: Plus 1 for the react icon.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom' 


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

try like this